# Prove certain subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1. Show  $S=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n\mid x\cdot v=0 \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.
2. Show $\mathbb Rv=\{tv\mid t \in \mathbb R\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and describe $S$ and $\mathbb Rv$ geometrically when $n=3$.

I know I should check property of subspace, but in these two cases I have no idea how to start. Someone give me a hint?

Comment: So what are the properties of a subspace?

Comment: 1. Show that if $x\cdot v=0$ and $y\cdot v=0$ then $(x+y)\cdot v=0$, and for any real $\alpha$, $(\alpha x)\cdot v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the set is

1) nonempty

2) closed under addition

3) closed under scalar multiplication

here, how about I do the first one for you

1) Note $0\cdot v=0$ so $0\in S$; $S$ is nonempty.

2) If $x,y\in S$, then $(x+y)\cdot v=x\cdot v+y\cdot v=0+0=0$, so we have closure under addition

3) If $x\in S$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then $(cx)\cdot v=c(x\cdot v)=c\cdot 0=0$, so we have closure under scalar multiplication.

Therefore $S$ is a subspace